# Typescript: Self-reference an interface value as a type

Tags: typescript, state-machine, typescript-generics

I have a function which takes an array of objects matching an interface as a parameter. The function will generate a finite state machine with a property, a string array of values and an array of objects defining transitions.

I would like (if possible) to be able to infer the 'from' and 'to' parameters on the transitions array as a literal union of the `states` property (an array of potential states). My current attempt only narrows the type to `string` and `string[]` on the `Transition` interface. Ideally in the example below `S` should be `'one' | 'two'`

```
interface Transition<S> {
  from: S,
  to: S[],
}

interface StateMachineDescriptor<T> {
  property: string;
  states: T[];
  transitions: Array<Transition<this['states'][number]>>;
}

function fsm<T>(opts: Array<StateMachineDescriptor<T>>) {
  return opts;
}

fsm([{
  property: 'test',
  states: ['one', 'two'],
  transitions: [{
    from: 'one',
    to: ['foo'],
  }]
}])
```

Typescript version is 3.7, link to a demo is here:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=23&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpTiAzsMwD2IAPAMoB8yA3gFDLIxT4C2AXMiQDS3Jj5skBtALpcAvtWqhIsRChJg4kALKIAFqAgARCFgRRgAB15QiqCjToHGB6GACebLGH0gA5gG5uTxTraphnnTOmDh4hFhsAIJQGHamGNi4BMRg6lgCAOTekFgZQgIgAK5MAEbQQmRknuLUMIUgCGEg9FhMpmQAFPhGEcjRsaQKymoa2rr6RvgmZmQAlFTcUBBghVDN3WBY1RIwrR0CFshW3bYOyBk5YBlcdNm+yJmEENfnYADu+Hk3PAmhyb0Hbh0BjMNgZJ7XIE8PgPDIwfCfETcURCago2ZAA

Comment: Can you change `function fsm<T>(...)` to `function fsm<T extends string>(...)` and see if that meets all your use cases?  If so I'll write it up.  If not, please elaborate on your use case to show where that doesn't work for you.  Good luck!